# $watch on input text is returning undefined

Tags: angularjs, watch

I am trying to use $watch in a input text. It's returning undefined when I type for the first time, and it doesn't work anymore when I try to type for the second time and so on.

What am I doing wrong ?

```
$scope.$watch('formNovoCred.dadosEC.representante.cpf', function(newValue, oldValue) {
$rootScope.formNovoCred.dadosEC.representante.cpf = $rootScope.formNovoCred.dadosEC.representante.cpf;

  if (newValue != oldValue){
    console.log("here", $rootScope.formNovoCred.dadosEC.representante.cpf);
  }
}, true);
```

Comment: Use the [ng-change](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) directive to react to inputs.

Answer (score 0):

**Understanding $watch**

```
$scope.$watch('scopeVariable', function() {
    alert('scopeVariable has changed');
});
```

The above watch function takes a scope variable, `scopeVariable` and watches for any change to it.

You wouldn't need to assign your scope variable to itself within this function as `ng-model` would be updating the variable. In your case your are comparing the old vs new. This is useful if you need to do something with the old value (re-set value to old if new is too big/out of range for your application).

Without a full picture of the code, about as much as I can help here.

**You can also try the ng-change method to do something on change:**

Angular's `ng-change` fires after each and every change. You can take advantage of `debounce` to differ change event until after a set duration. This will allow you to pause the event firing until say, someone would normally finish typing.

Add the following to your input element as an additional attribute. Also, ensure your input is tied to an Angular variable via `ng-model="yourScopeVariable"`

Example:

```
ng-model-options="{ debounce: 1000 }"
```

The `1000` is time in ms. 1000 = 1 sec.

You would then build your change function and add the call to the input as well like so: `ng-change="changeFunc(canPassParams)"`

Without more information, this is the extent of the advice I can offer. Hope you find resolution.